# printing value before popped element in stack [python]

Tags: python

Let's say my stack, S contains:

```
A
B
C
```

and when i pop the stack, if i print the stack, i only want to print the element before the popped element in the stack, is it possible to do so? In this case, C is popped hence it will only print B instead of both B and A.

Example:

if userinput is 'undo', what I'm trying to do is to pop the latest element i added into the stack and print the element before.

```
userInput = input("Enter option:")
if userInput == 'undo':
    L.pop()
    print(L)  #is it possible for something like (L-1)??
```

Comment: If L is a list, you can just use `L[-1]` to print its last element.

Comment: print `L[-1]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
userInput = input("Enter option:")
if userInput == 'undo':
    L.pop()
    print(L[-1])
```

This will undo the last add by "popping" it, then print the current last item in the list/stack.